# Does yarn install require the project source code to determine what packages need to be installed?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I have a node project that I'm using yarn as the package manager tool.  The project has a `package.json` and a `yarn.lock` file.  I am attempting to build a container image that caches all the files that were generated in `.yarn/cache` and `node_modules`.  So I created a docker image that just copies the `yarn.lock` and the `package.json` file and ran `yarn install`.  I noticed though, that the image didn't seem to include all the packages declared in the `yarn.lock` file and that file is modified as part of the install.  But when I copy the source code of the project along with the aforementioned package manager files, all the dependencies I expect are contained in the `.yarn/cache` and `node_modules` directories.

I find this strange because I would have thought that yarn would operate solely on what is declared in the `yarn.lock` and the `package.json` files.  Am I mistaken?  Does yarn also scan the source code to determine whether the dependencies declared in `yarn.lock` and the `package.json` are actually required and if not skip downloading them?  I'm relatively new to front-end development and yarn/node in general so perhaps this is indicative of a fundamental misunderstanding that I have.